# listbox does not update with new records added to table in access

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, listbox

I have a listbox on my search form that lets me search the table `Patients` using text criteria for `firstname`, `lastname`, `ID` and `othernames`. the SQL for the search Query:

```
SELECT 
    Patients.[Patient ID], 
    Patients.[First Name], 
    Patients.[Last Name], 
    Patients.[Other Names], 
    Patients.Gender
FROM Patients
WHERE (((Patients.[Patient ID]) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchTab]![txtI] & "*") 
     AND ((Patients.[Last Name]) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchTab]![txtL] & "*") 
     AND ((Patients.[Other Names]) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchTab]![txtO] & "*") 
     AND ((Patients.[First Name]) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchTab]![txtF] & "*"))
ORDER BY 
    Patients.[Last Name], 
    Patients.[First Name];
```

Search works fine but there is another form for data entry into the `Patients` table and none of the new entries are being found by the search form, but I can see them in the table.
 Anyone can shed some light on the problem?

Comment: Is the form opened before or after the records are added? If before, how do you update the listbox?

Comment: Is it possible the new data has null entries for `Patients.[Other Names]` - those records may not show up in your search

Comment: the search form is always opened and the add form is opened via a button on the search form then closed. I only requery the listbox, how do you propose the listbox is updated?

Comment: the null entries show up just fine.

Comment: been troubleshooting the database and the problem is in the search criteria. if I remove the part `WHERE (((Patients.[Patient ID]) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchTab]![txtI] & "*") 
     AND ((Patients.[Last Name]) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchTab]![txtL] & "*") 
     AND ((Patients.[Other Names]) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchTab]![txtO] & "*") 
     AND ((Patients.[First Name]) Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchTab]![txtF] & "*"))` then the listbox shows the new records.

Comment: narrowed it down to the OtherName field thats the one that is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:
`[Forms]![SearchTab]![txtI]`

With this:
`Nz([Forms]![SearchTab]![txtI])`

For all 4 of your text search boxes.

Comment: continued troubleshooting and found that the query works and finds all new records with three of the criteria, only when I try to add the fourth does it not find the new records. will try your code and post results shortly.

Comment: tried the `Nz([Forms]![SearchTab]![txtI])` but still same result, only works with three of the four fields, once I enter the criteria for the fourth field the new records are not listed